# Allow questions to be nominated for migration after editing in the /review queues

Tags: feature-request, review

When going through the queue of questions to be voted to close, I see a lot of questions that don't belong on one site, but would fit on another... If the question was cleaned up a bit. My options are to either VTC Off Topic, VTC Off Topic and migrate to site XXX, or Edit it.

I propose that when a question gets edited, it goes back to the main Review screen for that post, which gives the option to migrate the question after the edit, or close for a different reason.